# What else does the fabric of space-time do?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

I know that, the fabric of space is bended so there is a path for another planet to follow to cause gravity I.E. the sun and the earth ( i think)

Is htere any othe rthing's the fabric of space-time does to the universe? i heard some were about that it make's it so that all light travel's at the speed of light, is this true and is there anythign else it does.

Comment: Related posts by OP about the _fabric of spacetime:_ http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A14240+%2Bfabric

Comment: @Nick1o2 - I think you might need to revisit what you understand by 'fabric of space time.' It isn't actually a thing, it is a term writers use to try and help the lay-person understand some of the aspects of physics which aren't necessarily intuitive.

Comment: O clarify there is no "fabric" in the true sense of the word there is only the distortion of space coordinates due to massive objects gravitational pull.To address your second question Gravity ie "fabric" has a great list of effects on almost every aspect of the universe.

Comment: @Nick 102-The "fabric" term in your question may, whether you want it to be or not, be an allusion to string theory (-the threads in a real fabric can also be described as strings), which has been bashed in a recent popularization by noted physicist Lee Smolin; also, "space" is an aspect of spacetime, which is a more successful concept developed by Einstein and Minkowski to explain astrophysical data that had not been adequately explained by Newton's theory of gravity.  I imagine your hesitancy to type "spacetime" results from Google's anachronistic treatment of its typing as a spelling error.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is somewhat ill-defined, as "the fabric of spacetime" is a poetic term.  However, the modern theory of gravity is general relativity, which says that 'gravity' and the 'shape of space(time)' are the same thing.

To get some idea of how the above might be true, imagine two people standing on the equator, facing north.  If they both walk forward as straight as possible, then although they begin parallel, they will get closer and closer together, and eventually collide at the north pole.  If they did not know about the curvature of the Earth, they might conclude that some mysterious force attracted them to each other as they walked north.  In the case of spacetime, this 'mysterious force' is what we call gravity, but we see that it's not really a force, merely a consequence of the curvature of spacetime.

Comment: i asked for other thing's related to fabric of space, besides gravity.

Comment: I was trying to give you a better understanding of what is meant by the loose term "fabric of space", so you might understand that "is there anything else that the fabric of space does to the universe?" is not a sensible question.

The first step to really understanding these things is to learn special relativity, including the mathematics (this is directly related to your comment about the speed of light).

Comment: On the one hand, it's admirable when people her very generously give excellent answers to the vaguest fringe questions.  And on the other hand it's amazingly rude when fringe questioners are not gracious.